# equation in enumerate environment to long

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, enumerate

I have kind of a long math term in an enumerate environment. The problem is, it is too long, so it doesn't fit on the right side of the paper. Is there any opportunity to move it more to the left? As enumerate starts a little bit more in the middle than a usual line this should be possible somehow

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item here some text
\begin{equation}
this equation is to long, so it needs to be more to the left
\end{equation}
text\\
\item and so on...
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: In your case you could think of breaking the equation in multiple lines, e.g. using the `align` environment of the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `split`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
\item here some text
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a+b+c+v & = d+g+t+h+y+u+j+i+k+l+o+f\\
        &\phantom{{}= d}+r+t+g+b+h+y+n+d+e+r+f \\
        &\phantom{{}= d}+w+e+r+t+yh+y+n+d+e+r+f
\end{split}
\end{equation}
text\\
\item and so on...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on moving the equation to the left, put some negative space like:

```
\begin{equation}
\hspace*{-3cm}a+b+c+v  = d+g+t+h+y+u+j+i+k+l
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I will run and hide behind some tree for the last idea!

Comment: if you add a large enough negative space at the beginning, you can shove it right off the page to the left, and never get a complaint from latex.  but if you ever expect to use it in a printed book or journal, you will get just as many complaints from the publisher (or your readers) as if it stuck out too much to the right.